# How to verify each request with Spring Boot + Spring Security + KeyCloak?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am using KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Every time I try to access my spring boot application, it verifies the bearer token only once. Once the token is verified, I am able to access the (same)application without the token or even with token of a user who has logged out from keycloak ( both from Admin console I logout the user session and logout Rest API of KeyCloak).

I would like to verify the token each time there is request made to the spring boot application.

[Keycloak Client Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo0iG.png)

Security Config

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
            KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

   
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

   
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasAnyRole("Admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Application Properties:

```
keycloak.realm=xyz
keycloak.resource=abc
keycloak.auth-server-url=...
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings= false
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting Session Creation policy as Stateless for HttpSecurity.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                 .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasAnyRole("Admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```